# What kernel-headers deb do I need to cross-compile a kernel module for a beaglebone black?

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, debian, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I want to **cross-compile** my own **kernel module** for a **BeagleBone Black** using my desktop PC which has AMD-64bit architecture, and is running debian. The BeagleBone Black is also running debain, but the two machines have different kernels.

I just want to install the kernel headers for the ARM on my desktop PC, but I can't figure out which deb(s) need to be installed. I have the arm-linux-gnueabi-* version of gcc installed.

The kernel on the BeagleBone Black is this:

```
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone47 #1 SMP Fri Apr 11 01:36:09 UTC 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

What kernel-headers deb do I need for this?

These are the ones that I already have installed:

```
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all             
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-all-amd64       
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64           
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common          
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common-rt       
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64
```

Comment: I highly doubt you'll have any success with this. Kernel modules typically have to be compiled with the exact same headers and, most of the time, the same compiler as the one that compiled the kernel. You won't be able to 'mix-and-match' headers (especially x86_64 headers with ARM kernels).

Comment: I create modules with module-assistant. It's worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible yet - there don't seem to be any Linux header packages in Debian later than 3.2.*